# How to display long text behind an image and the rest below?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to display a text behind an image. I've tried with `vertical-align:top` applied to the image. The first text line is placed behind the top of the image, but the second one appears on the bottom of the image.

Like here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K39Cm/)

How to place the text that fits behind the image, and the rest below, filling the whole width?

Comment: The text that doesn't fit is already below the image?

Comment: @putvande - Yes, I just wanted to specify the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/K39Cm/1/

```
float:left;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! I had try with `display:inline-block` but didn't work.

Comment: Ok, well the code I gave will apply that to ALL images. If you only want SOME images to act this way, give them a specific class and then set the css to .yourclass{float:left}

Comment: Yes, I know ;) Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, just making sure! :)